# LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::UsersController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and I'm getting this error when calling a method in my Api. The thing is, the error only happens sometimes.

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::UsersController, expected /home/user/projects/project-name/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb to define it):
```

Relevant part of routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api do
        namespace :v1 do
            resources :users
        end
    end
end
```

Relevant part of the controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

I'm clueless of whats wrong, google a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: In what folder is the file stored? The error shows the location where rails expects the file to be found. Is it at that location? So `/home/user/projects/project-name/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb` exists? And from which class do you get this error? Easiest solution might to be to explicitly require the sometimes missing file.

Comment: @nathanvda I deleted the file and created again and now it seems to be working. The file location is the same as the error, the error happens when I make an Api call to the UsersController.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to the top of your controller
module Api
 module V1
  class className < ApplicationController
   ....

end
 end
end

This should follow your directory structure.